# Porting permutation function from Python to C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, python-3.x

I've been using an algorithm from a Stack Overflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9650593/4771889
Namely the permute2() function.

I've changed things a little for my purposes, and it generates the correct data that I need.

Here is my Python version:

```
def permute(list, nextFixable, num, begin, end):
    if end == begin + 1:
        yield list
    else:
        for i in range(begin, end):
            if nextFixable[list[i]] == num[i]:
                nextFixable[list[i]] += 1
                num[begin], num[i] = num[i], num[begin]
                list[begin], list[i] = list[i], list[begin]
                for p in permute(list, nextFixable, num, begin + 1, end):
                    yield p
                list[begin], list[i] = list[i], list[begin]
                num[begin], num[i] = num[i], num[begin]
                nextFixable[list[i]] -= 1


if __name__ == "__main__":    
    list = [0, 1, 2]         
    nextFixable = {0:0, 1:0, 2:0}
    num = [0, 0, 0]

    for p in permute(list, nextFixable, num, 0, len(list)):
        print(p)
```

I've simplified the usage a little there to give a basic example.

The output of this example is:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 1]
[1, 0, 2]
[1, 2, 0]
[2, 1, 0]
[2, 0, 1]
```

Since my practical usage for this is for longer lists (not the trivial "0, 1, 2") I REALLY like the generator functionality used here (the yield statements).

The problem is that Python is slow, and I sometimes have to wait a couple days to get a result.

I'm not a C++ expert, but previously I've found that C++ is much faster when compared with Python.  So you can guess what I did next - I tried to rewrite this in C++ (Visual Studio 2015).

Here's what I came up with:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream> // for std::cout
#include <vector> // for std::vector
#include <map> // for std::map

// https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/11/12/resumable-functions-in-c/
#include <experimental/generator>
using namespace std::experimental;
using namespace std;

using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::map;

void print(vector<unsigned short> data) {
    cout << "[";
    for (unsigned short i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
        cout << (int)data[i];
        if (i < data.size() - 1) {
            cout << ", ";
        }
    }
    cout << "]\n";
}

generator<vector<unsigned short>> permute(
    vector<unsigned short> list, 
    map<unsigned short, unsigned short> nextFixable, 
    vector<unsigned short> num, 
    unsigned short begin, 
    unsigned short end
) {
    if (end == begin + 1) {
        __yield_value list;
    }
    else {
        for (unsigned short i = begin; i < end; ++i) {
            if (nextFixable[list[i]] == num[i]) {
                nextFixable[list[i]]++;
                swap(num[begin], num[i]);
                swap(list[begin], list[i]);
                for (auto p : permute(list, nextFixable, num, begin + 1, end)) {
                    __yield_value p;
                    swap(list[begin], list[i]);
                    swap(num[begin], num[i]);
                    nextFixable[list[i]]--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<unsigned short> list = { 0, 1, 2 };
    map<unsigned short, unsigned short> nextFixable = { {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0} };
    vector<unsigned short> num = { 0, 0, 0 };

    for (auto p : permute(list, nextFixable, num, 0, (unsigned short)list.size())) {
        print(p);
    }

    // Keep output window open.
    std::getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

You can see I've referenced https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/11/12/resumable-functions-in-c/
which is what gives me the *__yield_value* feature.   (I presume this isn't portable, which is indeed going to be a problem for me eventually as I would prefer to run this in linux down the track, but for some early experiments it does the trick.)

The code runs fine, but the output is:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 0]
[2, 1, 0]
```

So let's compare to the Python output - it seems we have two lines missing:

```
[0, 1, 2] - Yes
[0, 2, 1] - Yes
[1, 0, 2] - Missing
[1, 2, 0] - Yes
[2, 1, 0] - Yes
[2, 0, 1] - Missing
```

Usually at this point of writing a SO question, the answer jumps out at me from having to explain the problem.  In this case it hasn't.

It's possible I've made an incorrect language assumption, and I don't have the knowledge to correct myself.

So to boil the question down - why is my port of the permute() function from Python to C++ not giving me the same output?

Comment: [std::next_permutation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation), unless you have a compelling reason to not use this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - Thank you.  While I'd heard of that, I did assume it would use an index based approach and provide me with duplicate results if the same int appears twice in the list.   A quick test now has shown me that to not be the case.  They should advertise the no-duplicates thing better :)  I suppose that's what "lexographical" referred to - woops!

Comment: Even if there were duplicates, sorting and calling `std::unique` would remove the duplicates from being used in the `next_permutation` function.

Comment: That would require storing the data somewhere unfortunately, and I can't do that with results that take 2 days to compute :)

Comment: `std::unique` does not store the data anywhere except at the tail end of the sequence.  No extra storage is required as all it does is move the unique elements to the end of the sequence.  [Please take a look](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f848eca2fbd7929)

Comment: Your results in that case are not permutations of the original list, they are permutations of a set - that isn't what I'm after.  It doesn't matter, because next_permutation with a presorted list does in fact do all I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided not to go to sleep tonight and find the answer by adding verbose debugging to both versions of the algorithm and studying how they differ.

The problem is this section of code:

```
        for (auto p : permute(list, nextFixable, num, begin + 1, end)) {
            __yield_value p;
            swap(list[begin], list[i]);
            swap(num[begin], num[i]);
            nextFixable[list[i]]--;
        }
```

To match the python it should be:

```
        for (auto p : permute(list, nextFixable, num, begin + 1, end)) {
            __yield_value p;
        }
        swap(list[begin], list[i]);
        swap(num[begin], num[i]);
        nextFixable[list[i]]--;
```

Possibly when pasting the Python code into VS it helpfully lined everything up, and thanks to Python's convenient lack of braces, when comparing the code again this went unnoticed.

This triggered a second issue where nextFixable[whatever] would decrement below 0 on an unsigned integer and overflow - but that's what gave it away.

(However as noted in comments I have taken on board the suggestion to use std:next_permutation in a do-while loop in conjunction with a std:sort beforehand.  That solution has in a simple experiment proven to be about 5-6 times faster than this algorithm.)

Answer (score 0):

I would structure it something like this (c++14):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>


// version which mutates the vector
template<class Vec, class F>
auto permute_over_inplace(Vec& vec, F&& f)
{
    auto first = std::begin(vec);
    auto last = std::end(vec);

    // permutation reequires sorted ranges
    if (not std::is_sorted(first, last)) {
        std::sort(first, last);
    }

    // remove duplicates
    last = vec.erase(std::unique(first, last), last);

    // call the functor for each permutation
    do {
        f(vec);
    } while (std::next_permutation(first, last));
};

// version which does not mutate the vector
template<class Vec, class F>
auto permute_over_copy(Vec vec, F&& f)
{
    return permute_over_inplace(vec, std::forward<F>(f));
};



int main()
{
    std::vector<int> list = {0, 1, 2};

    // an operation to perform on each permutation
    auto print_list = [](auto&& c)
    {
        const char* sep = " ";
        auto& os = std::cout;

        os << "[";
        for(auto&& item : c) {
            os << sep << item;
            sep = ", ";
        }
        os << " ]";
        os << "\n";
    };

    permute_over_copy(list, print_list);

    list = { 9, 8, 7, 9, 6 };
    permute_over_inplace(list, print_list);
}
```

expected output:

```
[ 0, 1, 2 ]
[ 0, 2, 1 ]
[ 1, 0, 2 ]
[ 1, 2, 0 ]
[ 2, 0, 1 ]
[ 2, 1, 0 ]

[ 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
[ 6, 7, 9, 8 ]
[ 6, 8, 7, 9 ]
[ 6, 8, 9, 7 ]
[ 6, 9, 7, 8 ]
[ 6, 9, 8, 7 ]
[ 7, 6, 8, 9 ]
[ 7, 6, 9, 8 ]
[ 7, 8, 6, 9 ]
[ 7, 8, 9, 6 ]
[ 7, 9, 6, 8 ]
[ 7, 9, 8, 6 ]
[ 8, 6, 7, 9 ]
[ 8, 6, 9, 7 ]
[ 8, 7, 6, 9 ]
[ 8, 7, 9, 6 ]
[ 8, 9, 6, 7 ]
[ 8, 9, 7, 6 ]
[ 9, 6, 7, 8 ]
[ 9, 6, 8, 7 ]
[ 9, 7, 6, 8 ]
[ 9, 7, 8, 6 ]
[ 9, 8, 6, 7 ]
[ 9, 8, 7, 6 ]
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort, and while your post reiterated info given previously in a comment by PaulMcKenzie (i.e. using std::next_permutation which is certainly better than even doing a port of the function at all), it doesn't offer me additional insight into why my question about the attempted port was not providing the correct output.  Additionally, the second example should have five items in each list, not four :)  I think there has been a misunderstanding about the meaning of 'duplicate'.  Thanks again.

Comment: @braks My intention is to provide a the basic 'c++ way'. If you can describe your algorithm (in the form of a specification) I am sure we can modify this answer until it suits your needs.